# Path to file in server

Tags: php, web-services, file-upload

I am trying to use a PHP file to upload files from an Android app to a web server.

This the PHP file:

```
<?php 

    //importing dbDetails file 
    require_once 'dbDetails.php';

    //this is our upload folder 
    $upload_path = 'usuarios/';

    //Getting the server ip 
    $server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

    //creating the upload url 
    $upload_url = 'http://'.$server_ip.'/danyra/administrar/application/admin/'.$upload_path; 

    //response array 
    $response = array(); 


    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

        //checking the required parameters from the request 
        if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_FILES['image']['name'])){

            //connecting to the database 
            $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect...');

            //getting name from the request 
            $name = $_POST['name'];

            //getting file info from the request 
            $fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);

            //getting the file extension 
            $extension = $fileinfo['extension'];

            //file url to store in the database 
            $file_url = $upload_url . getFileName() . '.' . $extension;

            //file path to upload in the server 
            $file_path = $upload_path . getFileName() . '.'. $extension; 

            //trying to save the file in the directory 
            try{
                //saving the file 
    line 45 -->     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$file_path);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `images` (`id`, `url`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, '$file_url', '$name');";

                //adding the path and name to database 
                if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

                    //filling response array with values 
                    $response['error'] = false; 
                    $response['url'] = $file_url; 
                    $response['name'] = $name;
                }
            //if some error occurred 
            }catch(Exception $e){
                $response['error']=true;
                $response['message']=$e->getMessage();
            }       
            //displaying the response 
            echo json_encode($response);

            //closing the connection 
            mysqli_close($con);
        }else{
            $response['error']=true;
            $response['message']='Please choose a file';
        }
    }

    /*
        We are generating the file name 
        so this method will return a file name for the image to be upload 
    */
    function getFileName(){
        $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect...');
        $sql = "SELECT max(id) as id FROM images";
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

        mysqli_close($con);
        if($result['id']==null)
            return 1; 
        else 
            return ++$result['id']; 
    }
```

This file is taken from a tutorial.
This is the scenario:

The PHP file is at:
http://myserver.com/danyra/android_login_api/upload.php

The folder where I want to store the uploaded images is at:

http://myserver.com/danyra/administrar/application/admin/usuarios

I am using POSTMAN to check the script, and I am always receiving this error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(usuarios/18.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/kokls/public_html/myserver.com/danyra/android_login_api/upload.php on line 45

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpMciKUa' to 'usuarios/18.png' in /home2/kokls/public_html/myserver.com/danyra/android_login_api/upload.php on line 45
    {"error":false,"url":"http:\/\/XXX.XXX.246.130\/danyra\/administrar\/application\/admin\/usuarios\/18.png","name":"fsd"}
```

I have tried a lot of options changing paths, but with no success.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: check the directory permission and the path

Comment: @Roljhon, the directory permissions are 755, and the path is correct

Comment: have you tried `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead of the server ip?

Comment: @Roljhon, yes I have tried and same result

Comment: can you update your post of what options for the file path you've tried and how you implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your current path is incorrect. You should be using a relative path.
Try this path

```
$upload_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/danyra/administrar/application/admin/usuarios/';
```